Intellij CE Debug Can't Connect
Unable to debug a JUnit test in latest IntelliJ Community Edition v2024.2. The test builds and runs successfully.
But trying to debug it fails.  It appears IntelliJ CE can't connect to the JVM the test runs in.

ERROR: transport error 202: connect failed: Operation timed out ERROR:
JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports
initialized
[open/src/jdk.jdwp.agent/share/native/libjdwp/debugInit.c:700]

Details about my IntelliJ CE

IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2 (Community Edition) Build #IC-242.20224.300,
built on August 7, 2024 Runtime version: 21.0.3+13-b509.4 aarch64
(JCEF 122.1.9) VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Kotlin: 242.20224.300-IJ

Details about my MacBook, JDK, and Kotlin:


macOS 14.3.1
OpenJDK 22.0.2
Kotlin 1.9.24 (also fails with 2.0.10)


I don't think I ever saw this error before from IntelliJ.  Also don't remember needing to manually configure IntelliJ to debug a local unit test.
Just for the heck of it, I fully removed then re-installed the latest IntelliJ CE. I also upgraded to the latest OpenJDK and removed older JDKs.
Anyone know why I can't debug with this setup?
Here's my Maven pom.xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>hey.you</groupId>
    <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <kotlin.version>1.9.24</kotlin.version>
        <junit.version>4.13.1</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-test-junit</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

Startup command Intellij generates to run the test in debug mode.
NOTE: Intellij picks a random debug port each time debug run requested.
/Users/bob/_tools/jdk/bin/java 
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:58502,suspend=y,server=n 
-ea 
-Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 
-javaagent:/Users/bob/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IdeaIC2024.2/captureAgent/debugger-agent.jar 
-Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug.enable.creation.stack.trace=false 
-Ddebugger.agent.enable.coroutines=true 
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
-Dsun.stdout.encoding=UTF-8 
-Dsun.stderr.encoding=UTF-8 
-ideVersion5 
-classpath /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/junit/lib/junit5-rt.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/junit/lib/junit-rt.jar:/Users/bob/_dev/mkv_exp/target/test-classes:/Users/bob/_dev/mkv_exp/target/classes:/Users/bob/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jackson-module-kotlin/2.14.2/jackson-module-kotlin-2.14.2.jar:/Users/bob/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.14.2/jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar:/Users/bob/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.14.2/jackson-core-2.14.2.jar:/Users/bob/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.14.2/jackson-annotations-2.14.2.jar:/Users/bob/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-reflect/1.5.32/kotlin-reflect-1.5.32.jar:/Users/bob/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/2.0.10/kotlin-stdlib-2.0.10.jar:/Users/bob/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/annotations/13.0/annotations-13.0.jar:/Users/bob/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-test-junit/2.0.10/kotlin-test-junit-2.0.10.jar:/Users/bob/.m2/repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-test/2.0.10/kotlin-test-2.0.10.jar:/Users/bob/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.13.1/junit-4.13.1.jar:/Users/bob/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter 
-junit4 foo.HelloTest


Previous similar questions found their problem was caused by something listening on debug port, or VPN interference.  I checked the port IntelliJ used and found nothing listening.  I also tried to debug with Wifi & VPN both turned off.  Still no luck.

Can you please include the full command used for running Java? Is the debug port occupied? Did you check out this issue?

I verified the debug port was not occupied, using a couple different port checking utils.  I checked the issue link you provided.  A difference between that issue and mine is, they got a connection refused, whereas my error message is Operation timed out.  Thanks for your interest.

After failing to get Kotlin debug to work with Oracle OpenJDK 22 or Amazon JDK 21 on three different versions of IDEA CE (2023.3, 2024.1, and 2024.2), I'm starting to wonder if JetBrains intentionally disabled Kotlin debug on the Community Edition.

Just discovered Idea CE's built-in debugger doesn't work for Java either.  Curious as to why Idea CE has a prominent Debug button when it doesn't work?

Maybe it's a bug specific to your setup in some way (e.g. other programs interfering) or specific to the Maven integration (it not recognizing Maven projects properly for some reason)?

@dan1st  This problem a big mystery.  I used Idea Ultimate for +20 years with no debugger problem. I decided not to renew my subscription in July, because I retired from programming.  Was hoping to keep developing as a hobby with Idea CE.  I uninstalled my Idea Ultimate and every support/config file I could find in my home dir and under ~/Library etc.  I'll keep trying to get it to work.  Next steps: Try debug when using Idea's internal build system.  Then try with Gradle.

As far as I know (as someone using Eclipse), (Java/Kotlin) debugging should work in IntelliJ Community Edition just as it does in Ultimate Edition. I could imagine the problem may come from you switching in a weird way (e.g. maybe you copied a part of the configuration but some are missing or incompatible with the Community Edition). Maybe you could try making sure you have a clean installation and/or try with a different user in your OS. Apart from that, you might want to check IDE logs. Maybe it's also because you opened an existing IntelliJ Ultimate project in Community Edition.

as described above my idea ultimate uninstall was thorough.  i never said,nor did i, open an ultimate project with ce.  as my question says, i created a new project with the jetbrains kotlin maven archetype.  all config & source files were auto-generated.  the macos log viewer lists a "build.log" containing idea info. no errors.  the error message in my question says it all. it's a miscommunication and/or mis-timing between idea ce and the jvm running junit.  that's all built-in configuration. the only thing i did was set a break point and click the debug button.

As of Aug 2024, with any recent version of Kotlin, Idea CE, Maven, and JDK I can only debug Kotlin remotely by manually using Maven & a custom Idea Remote Debug run-config.  Here's how:
First, launch Maven surefire plugin in debug mode:
mvn -Dmaven.surefire.debug test
It waits for a remote debug connection on default port 5005.
Next, launch this run-config to connect with the unit test's JVM. It'll stop at the first break point.


This is the first time I seriously tried using Idea CE. So far, it's been disappointing :-(
Is it possible JetBrains cripples Idea CE to force a paid upgrade to Idea Ultimate? Idea CE is portrayed as a viable, extensible Open Source editor (comparable to VSCode). That's not what I'm finding so far.
